# How to check User status is available or not in django orm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, orm

## How to check user status available or not and between start date and end date if same user

> 1. status canceled and another is approved create timesheet
> 2. status rejected and another is canceled create timesheet
> 3. status canceled and another is canceled create timesheet

> > IF User is status is pedning Dont create Timesheet

## Below is my code

```
def submit_attendance(request, approval_status=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        month = request.POST.get("month")
        year = request.POST.get("year")
        now = datetime.date.today()

        first, last = calendar.monthrange(int(year), int(month))
        month_first_date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), 1)
        month_last_day = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), last)

        two_digit_month = month if len(month) > 1 else "0" + month
        attendance_objects = Attendance.objects.filter(employee=request.user, date__month=month, date__year=year)


        leave_data = EmployeeLeaves.objects.filter(~Q(approval_status='Approved'),~Q(approval_status='Cancelled'),~Q(approval_status='Rejected'),
                                                   from_date__gte=month_first_date, to_date__lte=month_last_day,
                                                   employee=request.user).exists()
        

        leaves_data = EmployeeLeaves.objects.filter(~Q(approval_status='Pending'),
                                                    from_date__gte=month_first_date, to_date__lte=month_last_day,
                                                    employee=request.user).exists()
        print(leaves_data)


        for att in attendance_objects:
            try:
                print('test1')
                time_sheet_obj = Timesheet.objects.get(employee=request.user, date=att.date, status=1)
                time_sheet_obj.employee = User.objects.get(id=att.employee_id)
                time_sheet_obj.date = att.date
                time_sheet_obj.workingday_holiday = att.workingday_holiday
                time_sheet_obj.in_time = att.in_time
                time_sheet_obj.out_time = att.out_time
                time_sheet_obj.shift = att.shift
                time_sheet_obj.working_hours = att.working_hours
                time_sheet_obj.remarks = att.remarks
                time_sheet_obj.status = 1
                time_sheet_obj.save()
                att.status = 1
                att.save()

            except Timesheet.DoesNotExist:
                time_sheet_obj = Timesheet.objects.create(
                    employee=request.user,
                    date=att.date,
                    workingday_holiday=att.workingday_holiday,
                    in_time=att.in_time,
                    out_time=att.out_time,
                    shift=att.shift,
                    working_hours=att.working_hours,
                    remarks=att.remarks,
                    status=1
                )
                print(time_sheet_obj,'comming')
                time_sheet_obj.save()
                att.status = 0
                att.save()
```